# Ionic 7 browser autoc0mplete doesn't work on input of type email or text but it does on others

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, ionic7

I have implemented a ionic application with a login form...
in the login form I have 2 inputs, the first of type email an the second of type password, tryng to use browser autocomplete by the way it works only for password input.
I'm usign a controlled form so I modify the state every time that inputs value change...
Here's my input implementation:

```
<IonInput
                mode='md'
                type='email'
                label="Email"
                fill="outline"
                labelPlacement="floating"
                placeholder="Inserisci la tua email..."
                name='email'
                value={loginData.email}
                onIonInput={handleChange}
                inputMode='email'
                className={`ion-margin-top ${(isEmailValid && isDirty) && 'ion-valid'}            ${(!isEmailValid && isDirty) && 'ion-invalid ion-touched'} ${isDirty && ''}`}
                helperText="Inserisci una mail valida"
                errorText="Email non valida"
              />

              <IonInput
                mode='md'
                type='password'
                label="Password"
                fill='outline'
                labelPlacement="floating"
                placeholder="Inserisci la password..."
                name='password'
                value={loginData.password}
                onIonInput={handleChange}
                className='ion-margin-top'
              />
```

And that's my handleChange implementation:

```
const handleChange = (e: Event) => {
    if (!e.target) return;
    const value = (e.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
    const name = (e.target as HTMLInputElement).name;

    if (name === 'email') {
      setIsDirty(true);
      setIsEmailValid(checkEmailValidity(value));
    }

    setLoginData({ ...loginData, [name]: value })
  }
```

When i try to autocomplete with browser hints first the right email value arrives to my handleChange method but immediatly afterwards handleChange is invoked again with an empty string...

I've tried to change my implementation but it doesn't work anyway...
I've always iplemented my forms like this and it had always worked right so I think that it's something related to ionic...